# Apache Flink: Scope of ValueState in ConnectedStreams

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a custom `RichCoFlatMapFunction` that uses a `ValueState` member. The docs say that

> the key/value interface is scoped to the key of the current input element

See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/state.html#using-the-keyvalue-state-interface

What if I key on connected streams like this:

```
val connected = streamA
    .connect(streamB)
    .keyBy(a=>a.foo, b=>b.bar)
    .flatMap(new MyRichCoFlatMapFunction)
```

How are the semantics then? Is it keyed to the first, the second or the combination of the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of `keyBy` (`a => a.foo`) defines the key of the first stream (`streamA`). The second argument (`b => b.bar`) the key of the second stream (`streamB`). Both arguments must return a key of the same type, i.e., the type of `a.foo` and `b.bar` must be the same.

The connect operator will then, send all records from `streamA` and `streamB` with identical key to the same operator. The stateful `RichCoFlatMapFunction` will set the `ValueState` for the key of the current element, i.e., if `flatMap1(a: TypeA, out: Collector[TypeOut])` is called for a value from `streamA`, the state is set for the key `a.foo` and if `flatMap2(b: TypeB, out: Collector[TypeOut])` is called for a value from `streamB`, the state is set for the key `b.bar`.